# Как проверить доступ к файлу с абсолютным путём?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, пути

Есть каталоги с изображениями, к ним можно получить доступ по абсолютным путям, надо добавить в главный индексный файл проверки на доступ к данному файлу по базе( с этим сам разберусь) проблема в том, как при запросе на абс. путь проверить запрос через сторонний файл?  и в противном случае разорвать соединение(не error), а именно разрыв

Comment: Что ж так косноязычно пишете. Написали бы - запрещено отдавать файл если запрос на него со стороннего скрипта.

Comment: ну не совсем, запрещено отдавать если проверка условия не пройдена, ибо проверка по базе, ну в целом частично это так..